# Implementing an airbrush effect in paint program (using tilt from pressure tablet)

Tags: paint, trigonometry

I'm trying to implement an "airbrush" effect in a paintprogram, that takes advantage of tablet with tiltX/tiltY support. In Corel Painter, such an effect looks like [image]

Information from the tablet: tiltX is the angle of the pen in XY plane, tiltY is the angle of the pen in YZ plane. so I imagine the airbrush effect can be implemented as if there's a cone attached to the pen, spraying dots out the canvas within the cone radius. From the side I imagine something like this:

[image]

Would anyone know the math to do this, to calculate the x/y coordinates of the dots to put on the canvas in a randomized way within the cone.

A "spread" value would also be nice, like in the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Projecting points

A spray from a spray gun with radius, tilt, center pos, and direction.

By converting the problem into 3d you create your set of points (evenly distributed in a circle) on a plane that has a slope that is the sin of the tilt angle.

Thus a 2D point x,y relative to the center is move to the 3d plane by the addition of z that is sloped depending on the x position. Move away from the source by distance >= to the radius of the circle

```
z = radius + x * sin(tilt);
```

You then project that 3D point back to 2D plane by dividing by the new z divided by the radius

```
x = x / (z / radius);
y = y / (z / radius);
```

Now you just need to rotate the 2D points to the correct direction.

First get the direction of the spray as a normalised vector.

```
nx = cos(direction);
ny = sin(direction);
```

Then rotate the 2D point to align with that vector

```
xx = x * nx - y * ny;
yy = x * ny + y * nx;
```

And you have the projected point add the center and draw.

```
setPixel(xx + centerX, yy + centerY);
```

#### Evenly distributed circular spray.

Creating a even spray on a circular area requires a non even random function

```
  angle = rand(Math.PI * 2); // get a random direction
  dist = randL(rad,0);  // get a random distance.
  x = cos(angle) * dist;  // find the point.
  y = sin(angle) * dist;
```

The function `rand(num)` returns a random number from 0 to num evenly distributed.

The function `randL(min,max)` returns a random number that has a linear distribution from min (most probable) to max (very unlikely). see code for more info.

#### Example in JS

As the mouse can not tilt the spray is fixed at the center moving the mouse away from the center changes the tilt and the direction.

```js
// set up mouse
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false}
function mouseEvents(e){
 mouse.x = e.pageX;
 mouse.y = e.pageY;
 mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse"+name,mouseEvents));

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2;  // center 
var ch = h / 2;


// the random functions
const rand  = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const randL = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.abs(Math.random() + Math.random() - 1) * (max - min) + min;

// shorthand for loop
const doFor = (count, cb) => { var i = 0; while (i < count && cb(i++) !== true); }; // the ; after while loop is important don't remove


// draws a set of points around cx,cy and a radius of rad
// density is the number of pixels set per pixel
// tilt is the spray tilt in radians
// dir is the direction 
const rad = 40;
function spray(rad,cx,cy,density=0.2,tilt, dir){
    const count = ((rad * rad * Math.PI) * density) | 0;
    var xA = Math.cos(dir);
    var yA = Math.sin(dir);    
    doFor(count,i=>{
      const angle = rand(Math.PI * 2);
      const dist = randL(rad,0);
      var x = Math.cos(angle) * dist;
      var y = Math.sin(angle) * dist;
      const z = rad + x * Math.sin(tilt);
      x = x / (z / rad);
      y = y / (z/ rad);
      var xx = x * xA - y * yA;
      var yy = x * yA + y * xA;
      ctx.fillRect(xx + cx, yy + cy,1,1);;
    })
}


function circle(rad,cx,cy,tilt, dir){
    var xA = Math.cos(dir);
    var yA = Math.sin(dir);

    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i ++){
        var ang = (i / 100) * Math.PI * 2;
        var x = Math.cos(ang) * rad
        var y = Math.sin(ang) * rad
        var z = rad + x * Math.sin(tilt);

        x = x / (z / rad);
        y = y / (z/ rad);
        var xx = x * xA - y * yA;
        var yy = x * yA + y * xA;      
        ctx.lineTo(xx + cx,yy + cy);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    
}


function update(){

    if(w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
      cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
      ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
    }else{
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    }
    var dist = Math.hypot(cw-mouse.x,ch-mouse.y);
    var tilt = Math.atan2(dist,100);
    var dir = Math.atan2(ch-mouse.y,cw-mouse.x);

    circle(rad,cw,ch,tilt,dir);
    spray(rad,cw,ch,0.2,tilt,dir)


  
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
 
}

update();
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left: 0px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

#### Spread

As requested in the comments a spread value can easily be added as a factor of the tilt angle. It simply increases the y radius of the circle as the tilt increases.

```
spreadRad = rad * (1 + (tilt / PI) * spread); // PI = 3.1415...
```

Thus the point function becomes

```
angle = rand(Math.PI * 2); // get a random direction
dist = randL(rad,0);  // get a random distance.
x = cos(angle) * dist;  // find the point.
y = sin(angle) * dist * (1 + (tilt / PI) * spread); // PI = 3.1415...;
```

But this is not so easy to implement as a spray as it changes the distribution of points. I have added it to the spray function. The area of the spray is increased by the spread `radiusB` (area of ellipse `= PI * radiusA * radiusB` ) so I calculate the density on the ellipse. Though I am not 100% sure if the coverage remains constant over the area. I will have to experiment to know for sure if the solution is a good one.

The example shows a spread factor of 1.5, the red circle shows the original unspread area. I have also include mouse down to add spray so you can see how it accumulates (I have set the alpha value to 0.25). Rerun to clear.

```js
const rad = 40;  // radius of spray
const spread = 1.5; // linear spread as tilt increases

// set up mouse
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false}
function mouseEvents(e){
 mouse.x = e.pageX;
 mouse.y = e.pageY;
 mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse"+name,mouseEvents));

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const image = document.createElement("canvas");
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2;  // center 
var ch = h / 2;


// the random functions
const rand  = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const randL = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.abs(Math.random() + Math.random() - 1) * (max - min) + min;

// shorthand for loop
const doFor = (count, cb) => { var i = 0; while (i < count && cb(i++) !== true); }; // the ; after while loop is important don't remove


// draws a set of points around cx,cy and a radius of rad
// density is the number of pixels set per pixel
// tilt is the spray tilt in radians
// dir is the direction 
function spray(ctx,rad,cx,cy,density=0.2,tilt, dir){
    const spreadRad = rad * (1 + (tilt / Math.PI) * spread);
    const count = ((rad * spreadRad * Math.PI) * density) | 0;
    var xA = Math.cos(dir);
    var yA = Math.sin(dir);    
    doFor(count,i=>{
      const angle = rand(Math.PI * 2);
      const dist = randL(rad,0);
      var x = Math.cos(angle) * dist;
      var y = Math.sin(angle) * dist * (1 + (tilt / Math.PI) * spread);
      const z = rad + x * Math.sin(tilt);
      x = x / (z / rad);
      y = y / (z/ rad);
      var xx = x * xA - y * yA;
      var yy = x * yA + y * xA;
      ctx.fillRect(xx + cx, yy + cy,1,1);;
    })
}


function circle(rad,cx,cy,tilt, dir, spread){
    var xA = Math.cos(dir);
    var yA = Math.sin(dir);
    const spreadRad = rad * (1 + (tilt / Math.PI) * spread);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;     
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i ++){
        var ang = (i / 100) * Math.PI * 2;
        var x = Math.cos(ang) * rad;
        var y = Math.sin(ang) * spreadRad;
        var z = rad + x * Math.sin(tilt);

        x = x / (z / rad);
        y = y / (z/ rad);
        var xx = x * xA - y * yA;
        var yy = x * yA + y * xA;      
        ctx.lineTo(xx + cx,yy + cy);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    
}


function update(){

    if(w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
      cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
      ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
      image.width = w;
      image.height = h;
    }else{
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    }
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
    var dist = Math.hypot(cw-mouse.x,ch-mouse.y);
    var tilt = Math.atan2(dist,100);
    var dir = Math.atan2(ch-mouse.y,cw-mouse.x);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    circle(rad,cw,ch,tilt,dir,0);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    circle(rad,cw,ch,tilt,dir,spread);
    if(mouse.button){
        const ct = image.getContext("2d");
        ct.globalAlpha = 0.25;
        spray(ct,rad,cw,ch,0.2,tilt,dir,spread);
        ct.globalAlpha = 1;

    }else{
        spray(ctx,rad,cw,ch,0.2,tilt,dir,spread);
    }


  
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
 
}

update();
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left: 0px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, how would you add some kind of "spread" value, so that even with a smaller starting radius, it spreads more. (Updated my question with a picture to show that)

Comment: @user1643428 I have updated the answer to include a spread value. Though I am not 100% sure that it maintains a consistent density when the tilt increases.

Comment: @user1643428 I have checked the density (random even distribution) function and it still holds true for with the spread value, so updated answer is all good.